# Unhandled exception at 0x ... in w3wp.exe: 0x ... : A heap has been corrupted

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, heap-corruption, w3wp

I'm building a project in Visual Studio 2012. When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the app, it works just fine, however when I load it up in IIS7 on my Windows Pro box, the first time I make a call to a specific code base, I get the following error.

> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x4d8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   
>   Unhandled exception at 0x7797e6c3 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.
>   
>   First-chance exception at 0x778e32a0 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading  location 0x2039a9f2.
>   
>   Unhandled exception at 0x778e32a0 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x2039a9f2.

Now I've attached the `w3wp.exe` to the VS2012 debugger, but to be honest, I'm not sure how to debug this type of crash.

For reference, the code base that's being called in a WebAPI controller that makes a call to the ActiveHome SDK to control some automation bits.

```
            // GET api/<controller>/5
    public StatusModel Post(CommandModel command)
    {
        var activeHome = new ActiveHomeClass();
        // execute command
        var info = activeHome.SendAction(command.SendAction, String.Format("{0} {1}", command.Device, command.Command));

        // return results
        var status = new StatusModel { Device = command.Device, Status = info };

        activeHome = null;

        return status;
    }
```

*Note: I am compiling everything to use x86*

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204649/access-violation-reading-location-0x0000000c) looks similar to my issue, since my Win7 box is 64bit, but I'm still not sure where I'm going wrong.