# How can I handle the exception which throws on an external dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, exception

I have developed a project which uses an external dll as FTPServer, I have created the  FTP Server on my project like this:

`private ClsFTPServer _ClsFTPServer;

_ClsFTPServer = new ClsFTPServer(FTPUserName, FTPPassword, FTPPath);`

The Code above creates an instance of FTP server class, the class starts the FTPserver on it's constructor, it works fine independently as a module while the clients send their request correctly, but when an incorrect request comes to FTP server it throws an exception and cause my application to  crash.

How can I handle the exception thrown by the external dll to prevent my application from crashing?

Comment: Your external dll shouldn't really be throwing exceptions from threads other than the calling thread, do you have the ability to modify the dll code?  A better way to handle errors would be for the dll to fire an event when an error occurs and subscribe to that event in your main program (which is consuming the dll)

Comment: try catching appDomain/threading exceptions in your application- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx (added answer with link to more info)

Comment: An FTP server should always handle protocol violations itself without crashing.  Throw this one away and look for another one.

Comment: @NDJ i chatchet the  appDomain/threading  but the exception didn't throw there.

Comment: updating answer with code sample.  What exception are you seeing?  Does the appdomain event fire?

Comment: @RobJohnson Unfortunatlly i don't have access to th dll code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently answered a similar (ish) question which may prove useful - 
[Catch completely unexpected error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773662/catch-completely-unexpected-error/14773698#14773698)

EDIT.  I have to agree with Hans' comment above - might be an idea to find another FTP server.

Just for completeness, here's the appdomain/thread exception setup from - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler  (ErrorHandlerForm.Form1_UIThreadException);

// Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through 
// our handler.
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

// Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

Comment: The AppDomain.UnhandledException fires but the app still terminates:( the exception is:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: unless you're doing something in the event handler to cause the object reference not set, then I really don't know sorry - all I can suggest is to try another FTP server.

Answer (score 2):

In case of using external unmanaged\unsafe code, .NET (above .net 4) by default cannot handle Memory Access Violation exceptions that happens inside of dll code. 
in order to catch these kind of exceptions, there is three things to do. I did them and it worked for me:

1. Add these Attributes to the method that exception occurred inside of it :
   (the method that calls the method of the unmanaged code.)

   ```
   [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
   [SecurityCritical]
   ```
2. Add this tag to **App.Config** file below **runtime** tag :

   ```
   <runtime>
   <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true"/>
   <!-- other tags -->
   </runtime>
   ```
3. Catch these kind of exception by using System.AccessViolationException exception type :

   ```
     try{
           //Method call that cause Memory Access violation Exeption
        }
   catch (System.AccessViolationException exception)
        {
           //Handle the exception here
         }
   ```

What i said is just the cure for these type of exception. for more information about this exception's ego and how this approach works, see [System.AccessViolationException](https://airbrake.io/blog/dotnet-exception-handling/system-accessviolationexception)

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already tried this, but just in case, have you tried wrapping it in a `try catch`?

```
try
{
    _ClsFTPServer = new ClsFTPServer(FTPUserName, FTPPassword, FTPPath);
    ...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How didn't it work? You need to be more verbose or we're unable to come up with a solution. "It didn't work" is as helpful as saying to a doctor "it hurts". Where does it hurt? What kind of pain?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work, i mean, i added the try{}catch block and moved the instantiation of the mentioned class whithin the try block, but when that class failed that catch block didn't work, instead i have handled the  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event, this events occures and cause to app to be terminated.

Comment: @AdamKDean - you asked him to explain "it didn't worked" and he explained it with: "that catch block didn't work". I rarely downvote. BUT now will downvote his question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I hope he fixed it. But I don't think we'll ever know. I've been waiting for five years and still...here we are.

Answer (score -3):

By putting a try...catch block around every call into the object and its methods.

Something like:

```
try
{
    // use the DLL in some way
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // Handle the exception, maybe display a warning, log an event, etc.)
}
```

Also note that while running under Visual Studio, if you go to the "Debug" menu and select "Exceptions..." it will allow the debugger to break on ALL exceptions if you start your program under the debugger, and not just unhandled exceptions. Just click the 'Thrown' checkbox next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Comment: you catch ALL exceptions here. you shouldn't

Comment: Actually, it catches everything that is an Exception, or derived from the Exception class. It doesn’t catch everything. I also disagree with the blanket statement that ‘“you shouldn’t”, because if you read the original question, the OP is specifically trying to stop an exception thrown by a DLL used by someone else’s code from crashing his own application. If you have a better way of achieving that, please write an answer that explains how.

Comment: sorry. you are right. it doesn't catches 'everything'. it catches *most* of the exceptions.

Comment: what about catching only the specific error that the program raises (and which m-abdi forgot to tell us)?

Comment: We weren’t given that information, so I can’t comment on it. Ideally, the documentation of the DLL would tell us which exceptions it could throw, and then we could catch just those. Since the question is now five years old and I got 5 downvotes because of it, I’m not losing too much sleep over it though. I just tried to answer the question as asked.